# Shared Prefrence Not working for storing text as cache android

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

On My activity oncreate, I have defined the edittext and button to store the data on save button click, by using shared preference, but its not storing the data, whenever I get back to the same activity again, I don't understand why it's not storing. Here is my full code. While debugging I saw that its getting stored on this activity, after the finish of this activity the cache gets cleared.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText name1, name2, name3, name4, name5, name6, name7, name8, name9, name10, phoneName, phoneContact, contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4, contact5, contact6, contact7, contact8, contact9, contact10;
    Button saveButton;
    private Context context;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editorcache;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sos);

        context = this.getApplicationContext();

        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

        name1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name1));
        name2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name2));
        name3 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name3));
        name4 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name4));
        name5 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name5));
        name6 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name6));
        name7 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name7));
        name8 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name8));
        name9 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name9));
        name10 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.name10));

        contact1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact1));
        contact2 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact2));
        contact3 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact3));
        contact4 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact4));
        contact5 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact5));
        contact6 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact6));
        contact7 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact7));
        contact8 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact8));
        contact9 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact9));
        contact10 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact10));

        phoneName = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneName));
        phoneContact = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.phoneContact));

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPrefcache = context.getSharedPreferences("Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                editorcache = sharedPrefcache.edit();
                editorcache.putString("name1", name1.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name2", name2.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name3", name3.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name4", name4.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name5", name5.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name6", name6.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name7", name7.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name8", name8.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name9", name9.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("name10", name10.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact1", contact1.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact2", contact2.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact3", contact3.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact4", contact4.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact5", contact5.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact6", contact6.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact7", contact7.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact8", contact8.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact9", contact9.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("contact10",contact10.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("phoneName",phoneName.getText().toString());
                editorcache.putString("phoneContact",phoneContact.getText().toString());
                editorcache.commit();
                finish();
            }
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: post complete code and make sure of no typo for `ContactDetails`

Comment: How did you try to retrieve these ? share your code.

Comment: It seems promosing code. Please show how to fetch data from SharedPreference.

Comment: how to initialize "editorcache "???

Comment: Here is my full code, -@Pavneet_Singh

Comment: nope it's not , what is `getPhoneNumber(name,getApplicationContext());`?  and where you are tying to fetch it ?

Comment: might be possible getPhoneNumber() have some error and handled by try/catch and return. did you debug the code that going after getPhoneNumber() method?

Comment: actually get phone number is used to call to get name and number from the phonebook of my device, it working properly, there is no issue, the data too get displayed properly, the problem is arising after the activity has been finished, the data gets cleared. and before entering that function, I had manually entered the text. that time also it was not working

Comment: See @Pavneet_Singh I have remove those getphone number, and updated my code, still its not working

Comment: @SaurabhYadav no difference , ok  tell me how do you know `after the finish of this activity the cache gets cleared.`?

Comment: On LogCat, there was this D/ActivityThreadInjector: clearCachedDrawables. shown over there @Pavneet_Singh

Comment: Still my problem have not been solved @Pavneet_Singh

Answer (score 0):

Move these code to outside onclick method then i think you will get those details

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefcache = context.getSharedPreferences("Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
editorcache = sharedPrefcache.edit();
```

Comment: where you are fetching those details from shared preferences

Comment: First it should stored know, then only I can fetch it, I want to fetch that from my another activity

Comment: before finish try to get details from shared prefence

Answer (score 0):

Just check below answer

> store data in SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefcache = 
MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("Details", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editorcache = sharedPrefcache.edit();
editorcache.putString("id", "123");
editorcache.putString("name", "nikhil");
editorcache.commit();
finish();
```

> fetch data from SharedPreferences

```
String id = sharedPrefcache.getString("id","");
String name = sharedPrefcache.getString("name","");
```

Comment: @SaurabhYadav instead of my hardcoded values you can use 'editorcache.putString("name1", name1.getText().toString());
editorcache.putString("name2", name2.getText().toString());'

Comment: The same thing I am already doing know, so whats the difference, can you explain please @Nikhil Lotke

Comment: OK, can you also tell me how you are retrieving stored data from preference?

Comment: First it should stored know, then only I can fetch it, I want to fetch that from my another activity